# Finding city names in string

Tags: python, string, nlp

I have a list of strings (sentences) that might contain one or more Dutch city names. I also have a list of Dutch cities, and their various spellings. I am currently working in Python, but a solution in another language would also work.

What would be the best and most efficient way to retrieve a list of cities mentioned in the sentences?

What I do at the moment is loop through the sentence list, and then within that loop, loop through the cities list and one by one check if 
`place_name in sentence.lower()`, so I have:

```
for sentence in sentences:
    for place_name in place_names:
        if place_name in sentence.lower():
            places[place_name] = places[place_name] + 1
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this? I also run into the problem that cities like "Ee" exist in Holland, and that words with "ee" in them are quite common. For now I solved this by just checking `if place_name + ' ' in sentence.lower()`, but this is of course suboptimal and ugly, as it would also disregard sentences like "Huis in Amsterdam", since it doesn't end with a space, and it won't also work well with punctuation. I tried using regex, but this is of course way too slow. Would there be a better way to solve this particular problem, or to solve this problem in general? I am leaning somewhat to an NLP solution, but I also feel like that would be a massive overkill.

Answer (score 5):

You may look into [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) solutions in general. This can be done in `nltk` as well but here is a sample in [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-named-entities) - cities would be marked with `GPE` labels (`GPE` stands for "Geopolitical Entity" like countries, states, cities etc):

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc = nlp(u'Some company is looking at buying an Amsterdam startup for $1 billion')

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Prints:

```
Amsterdam GPE
$1 billion MONEY
```

Comment: from where i will get this en_core_web_lg

Comment: @ManuJose `python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg`